# Show that when $BA = I$, the solution of $Ax=b$ is unique

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm just getting back into having to do linear algebra and I am having some trouble with some elementary questions, any help is much appreciated.

Suppose that $A = [a_{ij}]$ is an $m\times n$ matrix and $B = [b_{ij}]$ and is an $n\times m$ matrix and $BA = I$ the identity matrix that is $n \times n$.

Show that if for some $b \in \Bbb{R}^m$ the equation $Ax = b$ has a solution, then the solution is unique.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $BA=I$ then:

$$Ax=b\quad \to \quad BAx = Bb \quad \to \quad x = Bb$$

Answer (score 2):

The usual method for solving uniqueness problems is generally this: assume you have two solutions, say $x$ and $y$. Then do manipulation, use theorems, whatever, and somehow show that $x=y$.

In your case, if $Ax=b$ and $Ay=b$, then multiply both sides on the left by $B$. Then $B(Ax)=Bb$ and $B(Ay)=Bb$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: from here we get to Ax=Ay, then x=y, correct?

Comment: If $Ax = b$ it does not follow that $B(Ax) = b$. You mean $B(Ax) = Bb$.

Comment: @Flounderer: Yes, that is what I meant :/

Comment: @n8sty: Not quite. We actually *started* with $Ax=Ay$, so we don't really want to go back there. (In general, a matrix might take two vectors to the same place; we want to "cancel the $A$s" but we need to show why this is allowed.)